# li element custom attribute not getting in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, frontend

I have an list where I have added dataset attribute like this

```
<li data-name="Correos" data-application="main" data-action="correos">
  <a href="#">Correos</a>
</li>
```

I am selecting element a and using that I am trying to get the attributes of LIST element like this

```
var parent = $(this).closest('li')[0];
if (!parent.dataset.action) {
    return;
}
```

Where `$(this)` is a selector for the `a` element. It is working fine in Chrome but in IE 10 it is giving error in console:

> Unable to get property 'action' of undefined or null reference

Any help would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `dataset` is only available from IE11 onwards - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Browser_compatibility).

To fix this you can use jQuery's `data()` method:

```
var $parent = $(this).closest('li');
if (!$parent.data('action'))
    return;
```

Comment: Thanks A lot.. I got the answer from this.